# ERROR: Cannot compile a minimal program. The toolchain or QMakeSpec is broken. While building ParaView to execute Qt custom apps

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake, paraview

I have been trying to build ParaView to test the custom apps examples [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/tree/master/Examples/CustomApplications) on MacOS.

I have followed the site instructions for the superbuild [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild).

Then I executed:

```
$ mkdir pv
$ cd pv
$ git clone https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild.git
$ cd paraview-superbuild
$ git fetch origin # ensure you have the latest state from the main repo
$ git submodule update

$ cd ..
$ mkdir paraview_build
$ cd paraview_build
$ cmake ../paraview-superbuild
$ ccmake -DCMAKE_OSX_SDK=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk ../paraview-superbuild
```

I enabled the CMake variables:

```
ENABLE_qt5
ENABLE_python
ENABLE_python2
```

Then ran:

```
$ make
```

The error I got:

```
[ 82%] No patch step for 'qt5'
[ 83%] No update step for 'qt5'
[ 85%] Performing configure step for 'qt5'
+ cd qtbase
+ /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/configure -top-level -opensource -confirm-license -release -prefix /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/install -I /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/install/include -L /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/install/lib -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtgamepad -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialport -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebsockets -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-dbus -qt-libjpeg -qt-pcre -system-zlib -no-openssl -skip qtsvg -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -qt-libpng
Preparing build tree...
Creating qmake...
/Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/qmake/generators/win32/msbuild_objectmodel.cpp:1190:10: warning: comparison of two values with different enumeration types in switch statement ('midlErrorCheckOption' and 'midlStructMemberAlignOption') [-Wenum-compare-switch]
    case midlAlignNotSet:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
Done.
Info: creating super cache file /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/.qmake.super
Info: creating stash file /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/.qmake.stash

This is the Qt Open Source Edition.

You have already accepted the terms of the Open Source license.

Running configuration tests...
Checking for gold linker... no
Checking for valid makespec... ERROR: Cannot compile a minimal program. The toolchain or QMakeSpec is broken.

Check config.log for details.
CMake Error at /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/sb-qt5-configure.cmake:47 (message):
  Failed with exit code 3


make[2]: *** [superbuild/qt5/stamp/qt5-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [superbuild/CMakeFiles/qt5.dir/all] Error 2
```

The `config.log` file:

```
Command line: -opensource -confirm-license -release -prefix /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/install -I /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/install/include -L /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/install/lib -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtgamepad -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialport -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebsockets -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-dbus -qt-libjpeg -qt-pcre -system-zlib -no-openssl -skip qtsvg -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -qt-libpng
executing config test verifyspec
+ cd /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/config.tests/verifyspec && /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/build/qtbase/bin/qmake "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" 'QMAKE_LIBDIR += /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/install/lib' 'INCLUDEPATH += /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/install/include' /Users/username/Desktop/dev/pv/paraview_build/superbuild/qt5/src/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec
> Project ERROR: QMAKE_MAC_SDK can only contain short-form SDK names (eg. macosx, iphoneos)
```

Any ideas on what should I do?

Comment: What are these `ENABLE_` variables? CMake variables? If so, are you sure CMake re-ran after changing these variables?

Comment: They are paraview-superbuild variables that I need. I re run cmake ../paraview-superbuild just to make sure but still got the same result.

Comment: What does the `config.log` file contain? Are there any clues there? Can you add this file to your question post?

Comment: I add the `config.log` file. It looks like I have to do something like `QMAKE_MAC_SDK=macosx10.4 ` but I don't know where. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `configure` step changed in Qt5 to accept only the *short-form* name for the Mac SDK. To achieve this through your build steps, feed in the short-form name when you call `ccmake`, by changing this:

```
ccmake -DCMAKE_OSX_SDK=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk ../paraview-superbuild
```

to this:

```
ccmake -DCMAKE_OSX_SDK=macosx10.14 ../paraview-superbuild
```